# MongoDB query only records that have two unique values together

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I have a few records on my collection and I need to find only those who have two distinct properties and group them by one of those properties. I've been searching for an answer but without any success (then again I'm still pretty new to mongo). To better explain myself I'll use this example:

I have the following data in my MongoDB collection (which represents requests made to a webhook, by whom, if it succeeded and it's content):

```json
{ sender: 6, domainID: "AAA", success: false, content: "Lorem ipsum" }
{ sender: 6, domainID: "AAA", success: true, content: "Lorem ipsum" }
{ sender: 7, domainID: "CCC", success: true, content: "Lorem ipsum" }
{ sender: 8, domainID: "CCC", success: false, content: "Lorem ipsum" }
```

Right now I've written a query that groups the requests by `sender` with `aggregate`. However, that's only part of the problem. I'm also interested in only obtaining the requests made to a `domainID` that failed for that certain user (and this is the part I'm struggling with). Using the prior data, the query should return something like:

```json
[
  {
    _id: 8,
    pendingRequests: [
      { content: "Lorem ipsum" }
    ]
  }
]
```

To do that I check if `success = false`, but I also need to check if for that `sender` and that `domainID` there are no other records.

My solution so far is this one:

```js
const unread = await WebhooksCollection.aggregate([
    { $match: { success: false } },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: '$sender',
            pendingRequests: {
                $push: {
                    content: "$content"
                }
            }
        }
    }
]);
```

My trouble has been checking if there are no more records/attempts for that `sender` and `domainID`.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the first `$match` stage because it will remove all senders with `success` status `true` and can mislead the next stages in knowing if there are any other `domainID` with a different `success` status.

**SOLUTION #1**

Grouping the `success` array and returning only those documents with all `false`.

```js
const unread = await WebhooksCollection.aggregate([
    {
        $group: {
            _id: "$sender",
            success: { $push: "$success" },
            pendingRequests: {
                $push: { content: "$content" }
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $match: {
            success: { $nin: [true] }
        }
    }
])
```

**SOLUTION #2**:

Counting the `false` value and considering only those documents with sum of `false` > 0.

```js
const unread = await WebhooksCollection.aggregate([
    {
        $group: {
            _id: "$sender",
            falseCount: {
                $sum: {
                    $cond: {
                        if: "$success", then: { $sum: -1 }, else: { $sum: 1 }
                    }
                }
            },
            pendingRequests: {
                $push: { content: "$content" }
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $match: {
            falseCount: { $gt: 0 }
        }
    }
]);
```